# React init : Error: sha1-psC74fOPOqC5Ijjstv9Cw0TUE10= integrity checksum failed when using sha1:

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

it seems the babel-plugin-jest-hoist is failed to install, but I do not know how to resolve it , many thx

here are the details:

anzhen @ banpingshui in ~/adam/project [10:54:29] C:1
$ create-react-app reactdemo

Creating a new React app in /Users/anzhen/adam/project/reactdemo.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

events.js:183░░░░░░⸩ ⠹ extract:source-map: sill extract babel-plugin-jest-hoist
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: sha1-psC74fOPOqC5Ijjstv9Cw0TUE10= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-psC74fOPOqC5Ijjstv9Cw0TUE10= but got sha512-O0NMz+Q+hIk8Srno7JfqGnQSfcAMk7JGk+cusrj+LLk+Xz0eW6zMt5FjZrpV3OR2blIQJR9EhYcyKp0y2wGf1Q== sha1-7Qoe24fAXU2xA3xfj0g9ijtfCCU=. (1518 bytes)
    at Transform.on (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ssri/index.js:310:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Transform.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
events.js:183░░░░░░⸩ ⠹ extract:cssstyle: sill extract babel-plugin-jest-hoist@2
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: sha1-psC74fOPOqC5Ijjstv9Cw0TUE10= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-psC74fOPOqC5Ijjstv9Cw0TUE10= but got sha512-O0NMz+Q+hIk8Srno7JfqGnQSfcAMk7JGk+cusrj+LLk+Xz0eW6zMt5FjZrpV3OR2blIQJR9EhYcyKp0y2wGf1Q== sha1-7Qoe24fAXU2xA3xfj0g9ijtfCCU=. (1518 bytes)
    at Transform.on (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ssri/index.js:310:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Transform.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
npm ERR! cancel after 1 retries!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/anzhen/.npm/_logs/2018-09-01T02_55_25_147Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.

Comment: Try the package's github issues page?

Comment: @jmargolisvt I'll go and find, but it seems not the package's issues, for I inited this project in another computer yesterday, and it worked at all. and i have just try this project in my friends computer(a new one), it return the same err with another packages.  thx anyway :)

Comment: well, 3 hours later I did nothing but run the command again, it worked now。。 LOL